# Error with pdf2pic package on node azure function

Tags: node.js, azure-functions, graphicsmagick, pdf2image

I'm building an Azure Function that triggers when a pdf is uploaded to blob storage then converts the pdf into a jpg file and saves it into another storage, i saw the library `pdf2pic` is good at pdf convertion, i installed GraphicsMagik, Ghostscript and the `gm` package from npm. I'm getting this error:

```
[2021-11-10T17:31:30.919Z] ERROR: Error: write EOF
[2021-11-10T17:31:30.922Z]     at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:16) {
[2021-11-10T17:31:30.926Z]   errno: -4095,
[2021-11-10T17:31:30.928Z]   code: 'EOF',
[2021-11-10T17:31:30.929Z]   syscall: 'write'
[2021-11-10T17:31:30.930Z] }
```

This is my code:

```
const pdf2pic = require('pdf2pic');
const gm = require('gm').subClass({ imageMagick: true });

module.exports = async function (context, pdfBuffer) {
    try {
        if (context.bindingData.blobTrigger.toLowerCase().endsWith('.pdf')) {
            const options = {
                saveFilename: "tmp-file",
                savePath: "./tmp/",
                format: "jpg",
                density: 100,
                width: 600,
                height: 600
            };
            context.log('Converting pdf to jpg...');
            const convert = pdf2pic.fromBuffer(pdfBuffer, options);
            convert.bulk(-1, false).then(output => console.log('OUTPUT:', output)).catch(err => console.log('ERROR:',err));
        }
        else {
            throw new Error('The uploaded file is not in PDF format')
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        context.log("ERROR CONVERTING PDF:", error);
        return;
    }
};
```

I'm using fromBuffer since the function is receiving the buffer of the pdf. I'm not sure if i have implemented the library properly, can someone help me?

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting, i convert to jpg because it's a requirement but if its better to convert pdf to another format thats ok, it has to do with the fact that this pdfs are rendered in a Hololens app, which doesn't have a library to display pdfs, second i don't think i can see the images in transit, the Azure Function just receives a buffer and i assume it's a pdf because this pdfs are uploaded via another Azure Function wich makes sure they are in pdf format, and last i'm open to any suggestion regarding what library to use, since i'm using an npm package called pdf2pic i have to use GS.

Comment: I undestand, the thing is that i haven't even made GS work on my computer so i would like to make it work locally first and then check out other solutions, thats the main issue i'm facing right now, how could i make it work using pdf2pic?